# How can I route my Angular API Calls through the hosting server?

Tags: .net, angular, .net-core, firewall

I have an application with an angular 7 front end and a dotnet core 2.2 API. The API exists on a protected corporate server, while the angular front end exists on a hosting server. The front end hosting server's ip is whitelisted on the API server's firewall, but because the API calls are coming from the user's IP instead of the hosting server's IP, all of the requests are being blocked.

For example, if User 1 has IP A and makes a request from the frontend application, it hits the API server with IP A, instead of IP B (the frontend server's IP). The request is then blocked because only IP B is whitelisted.

Is there a way around this? Can I force the request to come from the front end server's IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is you can send the operation details from angular app to your hosted server. Then based on the operation details figure out which API needs to be called. The call that API from dotnet core. And send the result back to your client. So you hosting server acts as a gateway between the API and client.

It also depends on what hosting you are doing. If you have an option you can write this gateway in NodeJS if there are limitations regarding the platform.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you suggesting essentially having a middle man API that makes the calls from the front end server to the real API server? This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Yes. This is what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

That's to be expected, it's the client making the request and not the server.

On the server where your Angular frontend is hosted create a simple proxy that receives API requests from the clients and then forwards them on to your internal server.  You can write it in nearly any language that your server supports.

Then update your Angular app to point to this new URL and all requests to your internal API server will come from your whitelisted IP.